# A question about an example of a closed and bounded set that s not compact.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

This example comes in one of my text books:

The closed ball $\overline{B}_{l_2}(0,1)=\{(x_n)\in l_2 : \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_{n}^2\leq1\}$ is bounded in $l_2$, but not compact.

It is clear to me that $\overline{B}_{l_2}(0,1)$ is indeed bounded in $l_2$ (because $\overline{B}_{l_2}(0,1) \subset B_{l_{2}}(0,1)$).

It is the proof that $\overline{B}_{l_2}(0,1)$ is not compact that confuses me.

In order to prove that $\overline{B}_{l_2}(0,1)$ is not compact, it is proven that there exists a sequence contained in $\overline{B}_{l_2}(0,1)$ with no convergent sub-sequences.

For each $k \in \mathbb{N}$ $e_k=\{0,0,0,...,0,1,0,0,...\}$ (such that 1 is in the 'k' position) is taken, it is obvious that $e_k \in \overline{B}_{l_2}(0,1)$.

Then, for all $k\neq j$ $||e_j -e_k ||_2=(\sum_{i=1}^\infty |e_{j_{i}}-e_{k_{i}}|^2)^\frac{1}{2}=(|e_{j_{j}}+e_{k_{j}}|^2+|e_{j_{k}}+e_{k_{k}}|^2)^\frac{1}{2}=(|1+0|^2+|0+1|^2)^\frac{1}{2}=\sqrt{2}$ $\Rightarrow$ $||e_j -e_k ||_2=\sqrt{2}$

If we suppose that there is a sub-sequence $(e_{k_{j}})$ such that $e_{k_{j}} \to e$ for some $e \in \overline{B}_{l_2}(0,1)$, then for $\varepsilon = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ there is some $j_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall j \geq j_0$. $||e_{k_{j}}-e||_2<\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

We take $i\neq j$, $i,j \geq j_0$, then using the triangle inequality:
$||e_{k_{i}}-e_{k_{j}}||_2\leq ||e_{k_{i}}-e||_2 + ||e_{k_{j}}-e||_2 <\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}=\sqrt{2}$

Then, $||e_{k_{i}}-e_{k_{j}}||_2<\sqrt{2}$, here my book arrives at a contradiction using that we've already stablished that $||e_j -e_k ||_2=\sqrt{2}$ $\forall j\neq k$ and, because $i\neq j$ then $k_i \neq k_j$, and here is the part where I'm confused.

At the beginning, from what I understand, $(e_j)$ and $(e_k)$ are two different sequences, but $e_{k_{i}}$ and $e_{k_{j}}$ are two elements of the same sub-sequence, so I don't understand why there is contradiction.

I think there is something else I've missed and that's the reason why I don't fully understand the proof.

I'd be very thankful for some help to clear up my confusion.

Comment: The $e_k$ are the unit vectors $(0,0,..,1,0,...)$. The norms are their differences which, intuitively should be $\sqrt{2}$ because any two of them can be put into a plane in which they are perpendicular unit vectors.

Comment: You are confusing the sequence of sequences $(e_1,e_2,...)$ with the sequences themselves.

Comment: A simpler and more direct approach is to use the definition. Take the open cover $\{ B(e_k, r) \}_k$ where $r < {1 \over 2} {1 \over \sqrt{2}}$. Then there can be no finite subcover.

Comment: @copper.hat So, the sequence that is proposed at the beginning of the proof is actually: $\overline{e}=(e_1,e_2,e_3,...)$? in this way, when it is assumed that there is a $e_{k_{j}}$ that converges to some $e$, it is assumed that an element of the sequence $\overline{e}$ has a convergent subsequence, but not $\overline{e}$ itself?

Comment: @Blue I am not sure what you mean. There are lots of sequences here. The proof looks at the sequence $e_1,e_2,...$ (each in $l_2$) and shows that no subsequence can converge to another element of $l_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence $e_j$ and $e_k$ are identical if $j=k$ and different otherwise.

And $e_{k_i}$ and $e_{k_j}$ are terms of the sequence $(e_{k_j})_{j\in\Bbb N}$, which is a subsequence of the sequence $(e_j)_{j\in\Bbb N}$. But the distance between any two distinct elements of $(e_j)_{j\in\Bbb N}$ is $\sqrt2$, and therefore, in particular, the distance between any two elements of $(e_{k_j})_{j\in\Bbb N}$ is equal to $\sqrt2$. But you proved that, if $j_0\in\Bbb N$ is large enough, then, if $i,j\geqslant j_0$, the distance from $e_{k_i}$ to $e_{k_j}$ is smaller than $\sqrt2$. That cannot be, since, if $i\ne j$, that distance is, in fact, *equal* to $\sqrt2$. So, there is a contradiction here.

Comment: I think I understand: in $l_2$, because the elements of $l_2$ are sequences themselves, the sequence I'm considering for convergence is actually $(e_1, e_2,...,e_k,...)$, so when I suppose there is a subsequence that converges, I'm assuming that there is a subsequence (e_{n_{1}},e_{n_{2}},...,e_{i_{j}},...) that converges; at all times I'm using sequences of sequences, so that $e_{k_{i}}$ and $e_{k_{j}}$ are elements of $l_2$ and in this way both conditions (the distance between the two of them is $\sqrt(2)$ and the distance is less than $\sqrt{2}$) hold and I have a contradiction. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thanks! you very helpful